# How to check the if config command name is changed in AWS Elasticache(REDIS)

Tags: amazon-elasticache, redsmin

I am trying to access AWS elasticache(REDIS). I followed this instruction:
https://redsmin.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/734646-amazon-elasticache-and-redsmin

Redis is connected now but when I click on configuration. I got this error:

```
"Redsmin can't load the configuration. Check with your provider that you have access to the configuration command."
```

edit 1:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config` Redis command is sadly not available on AWS Elasticache, see their documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html

> To deliver a managed service experience, ElastiCache restricts access to certain cache engine-specific commands that require advanced privileges. For cache clusters running Redis, the following commands are unavailable:

> [...]

> `config`

That's why Redsmin configuration module (it's the only module impacted) cannot display current your Redis AWS Elasticache configuration.

Comment: Then how we can add events like the Pic I have added? 

I used Terraform to create the elasticache

Comment: Either their documentation is not up-to-date or they now allow "config get *" command but do not display everything. It's might seems their "config set" command is disabled and the configuration-related command are read only?